# how to query nested JSON using mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have JSON like this:

```
"marks":{
    "sem1" :{
        "mark1":10,
        "total":100
    },
    "sem2":{
        "mark2":20,
        "total":200
    },
    "sem3":{
        "mark2":30,
        "total":300
    }
}
```

I need result  like

```
mark  total   sem

10    100     sem1 
20    200     sem2  
30    300     sem3
```

How can i achieve above format using MonogoDB `query.query` is jaspersoft related means very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good structure but if it is not in your control then you need something like this with mapReduce for JavaScript processing:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
      var doc = this,
          marks = doc.marks;

      Object.keys( marks ).forEach(function(key) {
        //emit( key, doc["marks"][key] );
        var matched = Object.keys( marks[key] ).filter(function(inner) {
          return inner.match(/^mark/);
        });

        if ( matched.length > 0 ) {
          //emit( matched[0], 1 );
          var myMatched = matched[0];
          emit(
            marks[key][myMatched], {
              total: marks[key].total,
              sem: key
            }
          );
        }
      });
    },
    function() {}, // null reducer not required
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
);
```

Not exactly your desired result, but this is the way mapReduce does it. You required this because your structure cannot be queried or analysed by traditional means.

To do it better you need this instead:

```js
{
    "marks": [
        { "semester": "sem1", "mark": 10, "total": 100 },
        { "semester": "sem2", "mark": 20, "total": 200 },
        { "semester": "sem3", "mark": 30, "total": 300 }
    ]
}
```

Then you query with the aggregation framework, which is much better as it uses native code and not JavaScript notation to traverse:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$marks" },
    { "$project": {
        "mark": "$marks.mark",
        "total": "$marks.total",
        "sem": "$marks.semester"
    }}
])
```

You can do more, but it is debatable on the sample given what you really want to achieve.

Comment: in that part i don't know at run time what value for mark. Then  how can i match using this statement return inner.match(/^mark/).And also records[key].total part "total" is not static that may be differ .

Comment: @user1177950 You need to re-read as you as missing all points completely. I'm adding code to match "mark" where your data does not clearly define if this is "mark1" or "mark2" or whatever. It's the data **you** provided. Nothing much else for us to go on. Secondly and most importantly I am saying **do not do this**. This structure is very bad and you should be using the structure that was given as an alternate. You need to learn.